# $\sigma$-algebra and disjointness

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Let $X$ be a [space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)) and $S$ be a [$\sigma$-algebra on $S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra). We often try to find [disjoint sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) that cover $X$ (a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of $X$) that "[generates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebras_generated_by_families_of_sets)" $S$, but what is the importance of [disjointness](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjointSets.html)? Why is it important for the [sets](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Set.html) not to [intersect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))? Can we not generate a [$\sigma$-algebra](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sigma-Algebra.html) using [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) that [intersect](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Intersection.html)?

Comment: I happen to be watching a [YouTube series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZ69KEg7ccU&list=PLBh2i93oe2qvMVqAzsX1Kuv6-4fjazZ8j) on this subject, for anyone looking for background knowledge on this question.

Comment: I've upvoted this question. Learning about this subject, it was not obvious why the generating function is defined in terms of intersections.

Answer (score 1):

You perfectly well can. For example, it is often nice to note that $[x,\infty)$ generates the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Disjointness is nice once you start introducing measures, as $\mu(E \cup F) = \mu(E) + \mu(F)$ (where $\mu$ is a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ and $E, F \in \mathcal{M}$) provided $E \cap F = \emptyset$ (and it is not true in general if they do intersect). Hence having a disjoint generating set can be helpful when you are trying to define measures and things like that.

Comment: Thanks! What motivated me asking this was a proof I saw in my textbook on the cardinality of infinite sigma algebras, which - the book claims - is at least that of the continuum. To prove that, we first show that an infinite sigma algebra contains infinitely many disjoint subsets, and so using these subsets to generate our sigma algebra we can show that it must be uncountable (power set of $\mathbb{N}$). But what isn't clear to me is that why we couldn't take *any* (even non-disjoint) infinite collection of sets in the sigma algebra and use these to show that the algebra is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer based on the explanation you gave as a comment to Keefer Rowan's answer.

Why is it better to have disjoint sets $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ to show your sigma algebra is uncountable:

If they are disjoint you can easily see that your sigma algebra has at least the same cardinality as the power set of $\Bbb{N}$ denoted by $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$. 
Because for each $I,J \in \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$ with $I \not= J$ it then follows that $$\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \not= \bigcup_{j \in J} A_i$$
So for each element from  $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$ you will find a unique element in your sigma algebra.

This is not the case if your $A_i$ are not disjoint! So you cannot conclude anymore that your sigma algebra has at least the same cardinality as $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$ so you can get no information out if it!

To see this consider e.g. $A_1 = \{1,2\}, A_2 = \{3\}, A_3 = \{1,2,3\}$ then for $$I = \{1,2\}, J = \{3\}$$ it will hold $$\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i = \bigcup_{j \in J} A_i$$

So the definiton above defines a mapping from $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$ into your sigma algebra by $$I \mapsto \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$$
If the $A_i$ are disjoint this mapping is injective, if they are not, it's not. And if you've found an injective mapping from one set to another one you can conclude, that the cardinality of the first one is less or equal to the second one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I also just thought of something similar: If we have a countable collection $A_{1}, A_{1} \cup A_{2}, A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3}, \dots$, then any union of subsets of this collection isn't generating anything new - so the cardinality claim isn't proven